# How to run script from shell script file in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, shell

I have created a shell script file - builscript.sh - and want to run it during Xcode build. Here is my configuration in Xcode

[image: build setting]

However, when I try to build my project script doesn't run.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Echo just prints the variable. Try this:

```
FILE=${SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_0}
`$FILE`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It saved my time.

Comment: any option to execute this script programmatically rather than executing it on build time?